# How to configure a Java library that uses Kalium to work on both Mac OSX and Android?

Tags: java, android, macos, java-native-interface

I have a Java library that uses Kalium (as a wrapper for Sodium) for encryption.

I need to be able to use the library on both Mac OSX and Android. Do I need two versions of the library or can I share the code? I've tried using Kalium-JNI but I don't see how to build things to work under OSX.

Comment: can you be more specific what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the library on MacOSX and Android. The [install guide](https://github.com/joshjdevl/kalium-jni/blob/master/INSTALL.md) on the [official github repository](https://github.com/joshjdevl/kalium-jni) actually confirms that. However, you need to build the library by yourself (beginning from section "kalium-jni installation").